# Cancel scheduled jobs with waiting status

Tags: java, eclipse, jobs

I schedule a number of eclipse jobs with a jobmanager that allows me to run 4 jobs in parallel. I can cancel scheduled jobs with waiting status in the progress view but I cannot find any listeners that fire when this happens.
Am I missing something, or is there an alternative approach to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IJobChangeListener` `done` event Javadoc says:

> Notification that a job has completed execution, either due to
>   cancelation, successful completion, or failure. The event status
>   object indicates how the job finished, and the reason for failure, if
>   applicable.

You can add a `IJobChangeListener` to each job you submit, or you can add the listener to the `IJobManager` to be told about all Jobs.